# Shift invariant in wavelet

Tags: wavelet, wavelet-transform

I always hear that wavelet transform is not shift invariant, and that there are other types of wavelet, like stationary wavelet and double density dual-tree wavelet transform, that are shift invariant.

Can anyone explain to me, what is the meaning of "shift invariant" .

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about math rather than programming.  dsp.stackexchange.com might be a better place for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shift Invariant (Time Invariant in Time Domain) means that given an input and its corresponding output, the output of the same input shifted will yield shifted output.

Namely, if F is the Operator, then OutputImage(x, y) = F(InputImage(x, y)).
If F is Shift Invariant, it means OutputImage(x - s1, y - s2) = F(InputImage(x - s1, y - s2)).

In the Wavelet world the property of Shift Invariance is usually achieved by skipping the Decimation step.